# JavaScript Ternary Operator does not work when the first condition runs through else branch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I got this line of code here.

```
 text={image.alt + " " + (uniqueLight.includes(image.id) ? uniqueLight.indexOf(image.id) : uniquePlug.indexOf(image.id))}
```

The third part of the text which is the ternary part, basically counts the number of elements I selected. As you can see, the conditional branch starts with `uniqueLight` and if I initally select an element from `uniqueLight` , it does not give any error and works well.

[image: Light choosen first]

But if I select an element from uniquePlug initally, it does not work.
[image: You can see the error in the console]

And if I swipe the uniqueLight with uniquePlug, and vice versa, the opposite occasion occurs.

How can I fix this or write that line of code properly?

Comment: `uniqueLight` is `undefined`... So you can't call `includes` on it. Your ternary needs to check if `uniqueLight` is set, first.

Comment: How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the optional chaining operator (?)

```
uniqueLight?.includes(image.id)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining